# What is this electric thing, hanging on an electric pole?

Tags: power-supply, electricity

Recently I found this plastic thing on a pillar in the village:

[image]

Looks like it is not finally connected yet, just attached with tape to the pillar.

What is it's purpose?

---

4 cables go down to this thing:

[image]

Comment: booster for a concrete rocket ;)

Comment: for about 50 ~  glass fusion splices in a waterproof box

Answer (score 16):

This is a fiber optic [splicebox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splicebox). It is a weatherproof enclosure where two (or more) ends of fiber optic cables are connected.

Yes - electricity poles also carry optical fiber for control of the network and often internet access.

Answer (score 15):

It's a junction box for fiber optic cables.

[Here you can buy a similar one.](https://fiber-optic-catalog.ofsoptics.com/item/optical-connectivity/all-categories-optical-connectivity-closures/closure)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

We've given your photo to the forensics lab and they suspect that it is a fibre-optic data cable using the electrical power distribution poles as the cable route.

[image]

*Photo 1. The enhanced image.*

1. The incoming cable.
2. The cable clamp.
3. The down-feed to the junction box where tap-off and through connections are made.
4. The cable out to the next stage.
5. The outgoing cables.

[image]

*Photo 2. A fibre-optic junction box. [Source](http://fibreopticcables.sell.everychina.com/p-105541004/showimage.html).*

The optical fibres can be run with power cables as they are insulating and there is no danger of fault currents going to ground.

Answer (score 3):

That is a junction box which is weather proof, and is probably temporary and will be moved before it gets played with.

Comment: Yeah - you'd think it'd be temporary, but in my part of the south that kind of 'temporary' sometimes hangs around for a year or 2 ...

Comment: Ahh, the definition of temporary - we were moved into a "new" office as a temporary measure - 10 years later we have been moved again...

Comment: temporary
ˈtɛmp(ə)rəri/
adjective Meanings:

    1. permanent